# How Backbone.js with rest based service using Asp.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I implemented some code using backbone.js in Asp.NEt MVC3  and found backbone.js very helpful. Actually I am developing  the data warehouse application where user at view side can run/save his data analysis. And after relogin can re-run the saved analysis.  On clicking the save button at toolbar system persist the analysis in DB.

My question is that can someone point links where backbone.js  interacts with  rest based service using Asp.NET MVC 4 so to save/retrieve the data in DB .

Please do advice me the better way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built several very large systems on top of ASP.NET MVC4 and WebAPI, with Backbone, recently. I highly recommend WebAPI. It's very easy to use, and works very well with Backbone.

http://www.asp.net/web-api

As one example of an app that I've built with it:

https://ravenhq.com/

The registration, login, management, and account settings are all Backbone on top of WebAPI.

Comment: Web API is nice but SignalR noise is also giving me hints to explore it as well. Any thoughts ?

Comment: We had SignlR in RavenHQ for a while. it got pulled out because we were having issues right before going live. I'm not sure if it got put back in. But I love working with SignalR for realtime data updates. I wrote a post about how I do that, here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/19/decoupling-backbone-apps-from-websockets/ but there are a lot of other options for making it work

Comment: @Derick Bailey how you handled authentication in your webapi, did you followed rest paradigm. or do you rely on cookies/ any third party.i have been pulling my hair how to avoid form based authentication with web api +backbone.js. the other part how you send the token/credentials via backbone. did you encrypt to base64.. ?